# Spark Structured Streaming application reading from Kafka return only null values

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I plan to extract the data from Kafka using Spark Structured Streaming, but I got empty data.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_csv, from_json
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, StructType

if __name__ == '__main__':
    spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("pyspark_structured_streaming_kafka") \
        .getOrCreate()

    df_raw = spark.read \
        .format("kafka") \
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers","52.81.249.81:9092") \
        .option("subscribe","product") \
        .option("kafka.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm","") \
        .option("kafka.isolation.level","read_committed") \
        .load()

    df_raw.printSchema()

    product_schema = StructType() \
        .add("product_name", StringType()) \
        .add("product_factory", StringType()) \
        .add("yield_num", StringType()) \
        .add("yield_time", StringType()) 

    df_1=df_raw.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)") \
               .select(from_json("value",product_schema).alias("data")) \
               .select("data.*") \
               .write \
               .format("console") \
               .save()
```

My test data is the following

```json
{
  "product_name": "X Laptop",
  "product_factory": "B-3231",
  "yield_num": 899,
  "yield_time": "20210201 22:00:01"
}
```

But the result is out of my predication

```
./spark-submit ~/Documents/3-Playground/kbatch.py
+------------+---------------+---------+----------+
|product_name|product_factory|yield_num|yield_time|
+------------+---------------+---------+----------+
|        null|           null|     null|      null|
|        null|           null|     null|      null|
```

The test data was published by the command:

```sh
./kafka-producer-perf-test.sh --topic product --num-records 90000000 --throughput 5 --producer.config ../config/producer.properties --payload-file ~/Downloads/product.json
```

If cut away some code just like this

```py
df_1=df_raw.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)") \
               .writeStream \
               .format("console") \
               .outputMode("append") \
               .option("checkpointLocation","file:///Users/picomy/Kafka-Output/checkpoint") \
               .start() \
               .awaitTermination()
```

The result is the following

```
Batch: 3130
-------------------------------------------
+--------------------+
|               value|
+--------------------+
|    "yield_time":...|
|    "product_name...|
|    "yield_num": ...|
|    "product_fact...|
|    "yield_num": ...|
|    "yield_num": ...|
|    "product_fact...|
|    "product_fact...|
|    "product_name...|
|    "product_fact...|
|    "product_name...|
|                   }|
|    "yield_time":...|
|    "product_name...|
|                   }|
|    "product_fact...|
|    "yield_num": ...|
|    "product_fact...|
|    "yield_time":...|
|    "product_name...|
+--------------------+
```

I don't know where is the problem's root cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things causing your code not to be working correct:

- Wrong schema (the field yield_num is an integer/long)
- Using writeStream instead of just write (if you want streaming)
- Start and awaitTermination of the streaming query
- The data in your json file should be stored in one line only

You can replace parts of your code with the following snippet:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, StructType, LongType

    product_schema = StructType() \
        .add("product_name", StringType()) \
        .add("product_factory", StringType()) \
        .add("yield_num", LongType()) \
        .add("yield_time", StringType()) 

    df_1=df_raw.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)") \
               .select(from_json("value",product_schema).alias("data")) \
               .select("data.*") \
               .writeStream \
               .format("console") \
               .start()
               .awaitTermination()
```